# emberjs template compile doesn't work in rc1

Tags: ember.js

I have

```
Esploreo.TE.Views.ItemView = Ember.View.extend({
    elementId : "item",
    templateName : 'itemTemplate'
});
```

and a template like

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="itemTemplate">
  content of templat
</script>
```

and all works good. But i don't to want to use this type of coding. In previous Ember versions it was possible to write the template code in the definition of view, like this:

```
Esploreo.TE.Views.ItemView = Ember.View.extend({
    elementId : "item",
    template: Em.Handlebars.compile('content of template'),
});
```

but it doesn't work (emberjs 1.0.0-RC.1). This features is removed from this release?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a curious way of working with Ember! To answer your question though, you need to add `.append()` to the end of your `.create()` like so:

`App.ItemView.create().append();`

Obligatory jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MGXDe/

Whilst I don't know your use case for this, I can't stress enough that this seems a little too *curious*, bordering on bad usage of Ember.

Comment: I want to use this type of solution because i don't want to create an html file (or use the index.html) just for one template.